# How can I update my OpenGL to 3.0 or higher

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, cpu, linux-mint, cinnamon

I am trying to play a game called "Endless Sky" but the message it gives me is "Endless Sky requires OpenGL version 3.0 or higher. Your OpenGL version is 2.1 Mesa 19.2.8, GLSL version 1.20. Please update your graphics drivers." I am running LinuxMint 19.3 Cinnamon, processor is an Intel Core i5 CPU 650 @ 3.20GHz x2 (not sure what "x2" means) graphics card is a Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller. 
Is it possible for me to update?

Comment: You install the Intel display drivers.  If you still cannot run OpenGL 3 software it means your hardware doesn’t support it.

Answer (score 1):

Your OpenGL maximum level is determined by your graphics card/chip, not the software installed on your computer.

In other words, if you have already installed the latest available drivers and you're still getting this error, then your computer hardware is the problem, and you need to install a more updated video card, or you need to get a different computer with the necessary hardware.